# Get some data from database table in server1 to database table in server2 using a cursor

Tags: sql-server, database, cursors

I want to move some data from database table sitting in server to database table on another server using a cursor. I know how to use linked servers but I am instructed to use cursors. Assistance please I am new to cursors...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql. There is an example at the end of the page.

Comment: Using a cursor would be one of the slowest and worst ways to do this. But if you insist. You just have to put your `SELECT Fields from linkedserver.database.dbo.table` inside a cursor. Here's an example cursor: http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/ It's a really bad idea to use one though.

Comment: Thanks guys for the assistance. I mentioned that cursors are not good option to my senior but he insisted to use cursors anyway